# Button style in WPF application is not reset after click

Tags: wpf, button, styles

In a WPF application (.NET 4.5) I have defined a button with an image like this:

```
<Button Command={Binding RefreshCommand} Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
  <Image Source="refresh.png" />
</Button>
```

This basically works fine, i.e. the button's style is changed when the user hovers over the button. However the style is not reset after the user has clicked the button. The "hover style" remains until another textbox or similar control is clicked.

How can I "reset" the button style after it has been clicked?

Comment: Please share XAML of your ButtonStyleKey style

Comment: I haven't defined any XAML for this. It seems as if this comes out of the box with Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5.

Comment: That is because `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey` hover style will stay untill the control is unfocused, like in a `ToolBar`, you will have to unfocus your button to reset

Comment: Seems like pretty odd behaviour to me. Do you use visual states? That's the best solution to go for, I think.